# Why dynamic power consumption is always zero?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I want to get an accurate power report that contains real dynamic and static power consumption. I'm working on Xilinx spartan3 board.
My code has no errors but after selecting the "Generate Text Power Report" in ISE (Xilinx synthesis tool), always the power report shows that my design has no dynamic power consumption. (Why?)

### Power report :

```
Dynamic   =  0.00
Quiescent =  59.84
Total     =  59.84
```

### My code :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY SRAM IS
  PORT(
    clk  : IN  std_logic;
    wr   : IN  std_logic;
    din  : IN  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
    dout : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
    addr : IN  INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 3
  );
END SRAM;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF SRAM IS
    TYPE matrix IS ARRAY (0 TO 3) OF std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL mem : matrix;
    BEGIN
        PROCESS(clk)
            BEGIN
            IF clk = '1' AND clk'event THEN
                IF wr = '1' THEN
                    mem(addr) <= din;
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END PROCESS;
    dout <= mem(addr);
END Behavioral;
```

### list of warnings :

Design load 20% completeDesign load 25% completeDesign load 30% completeDesign load 60% completeDesign load 95% completeDesign load 100% completeWARNING:PowerEstimator:270 - Power estimate is considered inaccurate. To see

WARNING:Power:1337 - Clock frequency for clock net "clk_BUFGP" is zero.

WARNING:Power:1337 - Clock frequency for clock net "clk_BUFGP/IBUFG" is zero.

WARNING:Power:1369 - Clock frequency for one or more clocks was not found

---

According to the "Brian" comment I edit the result of power report :

```
Clocks    = 0.92 mw
Logic     = 0.00 mw
Signals   = 0.09 mw
IOs       = 0.15 mw
Quiescent = 59.85 mw
Total     = 61.01 mw
```

Comment: The warnings tell you. Since dynamic power depends on frequency, tell it your clock frequency. Search the help stuff for "timing constraints". Apply a clock period constraint and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian. I apply a clk period (20 ns) in "Timing Constrains" tab. I added the final results at the end of my Question. Is there any other changes or the power report is completed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian indicated in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383269/why-dynamic-power-consumption-is-always-zero#comment43215180_27383269), the reason your original power estimate had no dynamic power consumption was that when the design was originally simulated, it was simulated in a static state. That is to say, no elements of your design were toggling. The reason no elements of your design were toggling is because all elements of the design are sensitive only to changes in clock; if the clock does not have a rising edge, then no dynamic power will be consumed.

When you applied the clock frequency constraint to your clock net, this provided the simulator information regarding how fast you plan to run your design in actual hardware. If you wish, you could adjust the constraint (25, 50, 100, ... 200MHz) to see how the dynamic power is affected.